# How to split bas on cmbination of strings and white spaces and symbols?

Tags: java, regex, string

I work to decompose a conditional string as shown below, by getting rid of the meaningless parts and splitting it to array contains the useful parts only, as:

```
String s1="01:IF   rd.h && dq.L && o.LL && v.L THEN la.VHB , av.VHR with 0.4610;";
System.out.println(s1);
String [] s2 = s1.split("([\\d]{2,3}?(:IF))?[\\s,&]+(with)?");
for(int i=0;i<s2.length;i++)System.out.println(s2[i]);
```

The "01:IF", "with", "&" and any white spaces are separators and required to be eliminated.  The execution result is:

```
01:IF   rd.h && dq.L && o.LL && v.L THEN la.VHB , av.VHR with 0.4610;
          <--- un wonted space
rd.h
dq.L
o.LL
v.L
THEN
la.VHB
av.VHR
          <--- un wonted space
0.4610;
```

The space appears as first and ninth element in the split string. How can I get rid of these extra spaces? Also, I need more good examples on how to utilize the different options, mentioned in [split.regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html),  and how to combine them in one regex. Most Most of the answers in the Stack Overflow are based on one separator, no a complex combinations exist with illustrations. 
Thanks.

Comment: post the expected output? Why you want to do split? What's wrong with Pattern , Matcher classes?

Comment: i think you could set a condition  to not to print the elements which contain empty or blank spaces only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve the same using `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes.

```
String s1="01:IF   rd.h && dq.L && o.LL && v.L THEN la.VHB , av.VHR with 0.4610;";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?:\\d{2,3}?(?::IF))?[\\s,&]+(?:with)?|(\\S+)").matcher(s1);
while(m.find())
{
    if(m.group(1) != null)
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

I just turned all the capturing groups present in your regex to non-capturing groups and added an extra `|(\\S+)` at the last, which means do matching only on the remaining string (*except the matched characters*). `(\\S+)` captures one or more non-space characters.

Output:

```
rd.h
dq.L
o.LL
v.L
THEN
la.VHB
av.VHR
0.4610;
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fM9gS2/5)

Comment: Thank you very much,  helpful new efficient method. Also the links:  [Online Regex](https://regex101.com/r/mB4nA5/1#pcre) and  [Java Regex Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)  are very good.

Comment: I used this Regex : "(?i)(\s*\d{1,4}\s*:\sIF\s+)+|(\s,\s*)+|(\swith\s)+|(\s*&\s*)+|(\s+)|(\s*;\s‌​*)+" It works perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different strategy instead of splitting and sanitizing.

Assuming the entities listed in your desired output represent all the patterns you are willing to keep:

```
String test = "01:IF   rd.h && dq.L && o.LL && v.L THEN la.VHB , av.VHR with 0.4610;";
//                           | positive look behind for start of input or whitespace
//                           |          | "rd.h" etc.
//                           |          |                        | OR
//                           |          |                        | | "0.4610;" etc.
//                           |          |                        | |           | Positive lookahead for end of input or whitespace
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=^|\\s)(\\p{Alpha}+\\.\\p{Alpha}+|\\d+\\.\\d+;)(?=\\s|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
while (m.find()) {
   result.append(m.group()).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
System.out.println(result);
```

**Output**

```
rd.h
dq.L
o.LL
v.L
la.VHB
av.VHR
0.4610;
```

**Explanation**

- The `Pattern` here looks for positive matches rather than sanitizing and splitting.
- It includes the pattern for "rd.h" etc., **or** the pattern for "0.4160" etc., generalized as possible.
- It then iterates over the matches and builds a `String` with the desired output, one match per line.

Comment: But the number, in my case, can be any thing in the range 0.0000 to 1.0000 which means 10000 words for full  accuracy. This can slows the split process. But it is still good for keywords searching, thanks.